# Github n Commits 0 Files changed

Tags: git, github, merge, git-pull

My [Github Repo](https://github.com/phystem/Cognizant-Intelligent-Test-Scripter-IE-Toolbar)

I forked a repo and did some changes. Then I created a PR and successfully merged with the Main/Master Repo.

While Merging I chose the Squash Merge Option.

Now my Froked repo shows

> This branch is 14 commits ahead, 1 commit behind CognizantQAHub:master.

When I [compared for the changes](https://github.com/CognizantQAHub/Cognizant-Intelligent-Test-Scripter-IE-Toolbar/compare/master...phystem:master) It is showing

> 14 commits 0 files changed

What is the meaning of that? That means Only My Files got merged with the Main Repo?

How to make sure both Main repo and Forked repo in sync with each other?

Do I need to create a PR Again?

Comment: I think your squashed changes are already part of the remote repository on GitHub, so your 14 commits are "garbage" without additional changes. I would suggest to check out the GitHub master branch and ignore your commits (after making sure the merge actually happened).

Comment: @C-Otto So you want me to delete my forked one..Then Fork again??

Comment: Every commit that is not part of the server's branch is an implicit fork. So, yes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the same thing changed twice - as 14 commits and as a single squashed commit. Contents is the same, history is different. Most probably you should just drop your commits and reset your fork to main repo branch.

Comment: So you want me to delete my forked one..Then Fork again??

Comment: No need to delete, just reset your branch and push to github's fork with `--force`.

Comment: Anyway, I think it's bad idea to squash in github, it creates some noise. So, either don't squash or squash before creating a pull request.